# Tensorflow: value error with variable_scope

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

This is my code below:

```
'''
Tensorflow LSTM classification of 16x30 images.
'''

from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn, rnn_cell
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

'''
a Tensorflow LSTM that will sequentially input several lines from each single image 
i.e. The Tensorflow graph will take a flat (1,480) features image as it was done in Multi-layer
perceptron MNIST Tensorflow tutorial, but then reshape it in a sequential manner with 16 features each and 30 time_steps.
'''

blaine = genfromtxt('./Desktop/Blaine_CSV_lstm.csv',delimiter=',')  # CSV transform to array
target = [row[0] for row in blaine]             # 1st column in CSV as the targets
data = blaine[:, 1:481]                          #flat feature vectors
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.05, random_state=42)

f=open('cs-training.csv','w')       #1st split for training
for i,j in enumerate(X_train):
        k=np.append(np.array(y_train[i]),j   )
        f.write(",".join([str(s) for s in k]) + '\n')
f.close()
f=open('cs-testing.csv','w')        #2nd split for test
for i,j in enumerate(X_test):
        k=np.append(np.array(y_test[i]),j   )
        f.write(",".join([str(s) for s in k]) + '\n')
f.close()



new_data = genfromtxt('cs-training.csv',delimiter=',')  # Training data
new_test_data = genfromtxt('cs-testing.csv',delimiter=',')  # Test data

x_train=np.array([ i[1::] for i in new_data])
ss = pd.Series(y_train)     #indexing series needed for later Pandas Dummies one-hot vectors
y_train_onehot = pd.get_dummies(ss)

x_test=np.array([ i[1::] for i in new_test_data])
gg = pd.Series(y_test)
y_test_onehot = pd.get_dummies(gg)


# General Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_iters = 100000
batch_size = 33
display_step = 10

# Tensorflow LSTM Network Parameters
n_input = 16 # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_steps = 30 # timesteps
n_hidden = 128 # hidden layer num of features
n_classes = 20 # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_steps, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

# Define weights

weights = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}


def RNN(x, weights, biases):

    # Prepare data shape to match `rnn` function requirements
    # Current data input shape: (batch_size, n_steps, n_input)
    # Required shape: 'n_steps' tensors list of shape (batch_size, n_input)

    # Permuting batch_size and n_steps
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
    # Reshaping to (n_steps*batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n_input])
    # Split to get a list of 'n_steps' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.split(0, n_steps, x)

    # Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
    with tf.variable_scope('cell_def'): 
        lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)

    # Get lstm cell output
    with tf.variable_scope('rnn_def'): 
        outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Linear activation, using rnn inner loop last output
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']

pred = RNN(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    step = 1
    # Keep training until reach max iterations
    while step * batch_size < training_iters:
        batch_x = np.split(x_train, 15)
        batch_y = np.split(y_train_onehot, 15)
        for index in range(len(batch_x)):
            ouh1 = batch_x[index]
            ouh2 = batch_y[index]
            # Reshape data to get 28 seq of 28 elements
            ouh1 = np.reshape(ouh1,(batch_size, n_steps, n_input))        
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: ouh1, y: ouh2})      # Run optimization op (backprop)
            if step % display_step == 0:
                # Calculate batch accuracy
                acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: ouh1, y: ouh2})
                # Calculate batch loss
                loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: ouh1, y: ouh2})
                print("Iter " + str(step*batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                    "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                    "{:.5f}".format(acc))
                step += 1
print("Optimization Finished!")
```

and I am getting the below error that it seems i am re-iterating over the same variable on lines 92 and 97, and i am concerned that it might be a case of incompatibility with Tensorflow 0.10.0 on the RNN def side:

```
ValueError: Variable RNN/BasicLSTMCell/Linear/Matrix already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:

  File "/home/mohsen/lstm_mnist.py", line 92, in RNN
    outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
  File "/home/mohsen/lstm_mnist.py", line 97, in <module>
    pred = RNN(x, weights, biases)
  File "/home/mohsen/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
```

What could be the origin of this error and how i can resolve it?

EDIT: from the original repo where i build upon my code the same variable_scope problem persists https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py

Comment: You are not iterating over the same variable in line 92 and 97, since those will always be in the same namespace, since you are calling one namespace from within another (since one is embedded in the RNN function). So your effective variable scope will be something like `'backward/forward'`.

The problem is in lines 89 and 92. So could you please instead try:

    with tf.variable_scope('cell_def'):
        lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)
    with tf.variable_scope('rnn_def'):
        outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

Comment: the problem disappeared but a new one with the 'init' instance appeared: ValueError: Fetch argument <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation object at 0x7ff12eeabc10> of <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation object at 0x7ff12eeabc10> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Operation u'init_2' has been marked as not fetchable.)

Comment: this one reappeared again: ValueError: Variable rnn_def/RNN/LSTMCell/W_0 already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:

  File "<ipython-input-31-48d3e084980b>", line 95, in RNN
    outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
  File "<ipython-input-31-48d3e084980b>", line 100, in <module>
    pred = RNN(x, weights, biases)
  File "/home/mohsen/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

Comment: could you please update your question to the newest code? That way I can see what you have at the moment :-)

Comment: @cleros yes i will do it. If u want a working example, u can check the link i provided in the bottom. It has a similar problem.

Comment: @cleros hello, i restarted a new dedicated session of Python and everything is working now. Thanks a lot. Please if u can post as an answer so it can be rated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tensorflow: shared variables error with simple LSTM network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941382/tensorflow-shared-variables-error-with-simple-lstm-network)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not iterating over the same variable in line 92 and 97, since those will always be in the same namespace, at least in the current setting, since you are calling one namespace from within another (since one is embedded in the RNN function). So your effective variable scope will be something like `'backward/forward'`.

Hence the problem, in my guess, is in lines 89 and 92, since both "live" in the same namespace (see above), and both may introduce a variable called `RNN/BasicLSTMCell/Linear/Matrix`. So you should change your code to the following:

```
# Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
with tf.variable_scope('cell_def'):
    lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)

# Get lstm cell output
with tf.variable_scope('rnn_def'):
    outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

This makes the LSTMCell initialization live in one namespace - `"cell_def/*"`, and the initialization of the complete RNN in another - `"rnn_def/*"`.